# XSLT 2.0 in Eclipse without additional library?

Tags: eclipse, xslt

Is it possible to perform XSLT 2.0 transformation in Eclipse without additional library (AltovaXML, Saxon)?

Comment: What does the IDE have to do with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is No. You need to install an XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select XSLT file Run As -- Runconfiguration
2. Create New configuration under XSL
3. Select input file(test.xml) and transformation file (test.xslt)
4. Select classpath tab and under user entries  add external jar (Saxon-HE-9.5.0.1.jar)
5. Select Output file from ouput tab

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but if you want to test your XSL stylesheets to see if they render your XML correctly, you have your choice:

- [Orangevolt XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-orangevolt/index.html)
- The built in XSLT features of the [Eclipse Web Tools  Project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project) (WTP)

Comment: You seem to haven't understood the question: "Is it possible to perform XSLT 2.0 transformation in Eclipse **without additional library (AltovaXML, Saxon)**? " OrangevoltXSLT, according to its documentation uses MSXML, AltovaXML and Saxon -- exactly the contrary to what this question asks for.

Comment: If you install the Orangevolt plugin, yes, it comes with Saxon and Xalan, but you don't have to use them.  It works just fine with the default WTP transformer.  In fact, it allows you to choose which transformer you want to use.

Comment: Hmm, @_Aaron Sheffey: We cannot know for sure what the OP wants, but from what he wrote it seems he doesn't want to have "additional libraries" installed and wants to know if there isn't some system-supported XSLT 2.0 processor (as is the case with some XSLT 1.0 processors). As a matter of fact, OrangevoltXSLT is also kind of "additional library" to be installed. So, the answer is negative :(

Comment: Hello, thanks for answers but key point in my question is "2.0". http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project states that XSLT 2.0 is possible but I am unable to run such transform with "JRE Instance Default" or "Xalan 2.7.1".

Comment: Gotcha.  According to this post (http://www.coderanch.com/t/455845/XML/while-upgrading-XSLT-XSLT), Xalan 2.7.1 doesn't support 2.0 transforms

Answer (score 1):

Answer: NO, as already stated by others.
But it is also important to specifying the use of **XSLT 2.0** instead of 1.0 (otherwise I got the error "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.icl.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found").
Using XSLT 2.0 with saxon can e.g. be achieved by:

1. Download Saxon (e.g. from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and extract files locally
2. In eclipse choose "Window > Preferences" then "XML > XSL > Java Processors > Add"
3. Fill in a "Processor Name", e.g. "Saxon XSLT 2.0"
4. In field "Processor type" choose "Saxon (XSLT 2.0)" !!
5. Choose "Add external jar" and choose your saxon jar, e.g. "saxon9he.jar"
6. Confirm by clicking "OK" etc

Now you can use saxon for XSLT 2.0 transformations in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Check
http://code.google.com/p/cakupan/

you can find a eclipse debugger plugin for xsl 2.0

Instructions to adapt it to eclipse kepler can be found at the forum, or at http://pjoseph.net/codecorner/2014/02/xsl-2-0-debugger-for-eclipse-kepler-with-saxon-he/