# Eclipse support breakpoints in .xsl-file?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xslt

i am wondering about eclipse's possibility to make breakpoints in .xsl-files.

It does not look like the debugger is able to stop on the line in xslt, while rendering... is there any hidden xsl-debugger?

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28830150/3820523

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Yes, It's supporting ...***

```
    Please refer the below links
    https://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project/UserGuide/Launching
    http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xsl.doc%2Fhtml%2Flaunching%2Flaunching.html
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago i did a lot of work with xslt. I was using the (commercial) [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) which has xslt debugging capabilities and a lot of other features which helped me handling XSLT. As i remember correctly they actually offer oxygen as an eclipse plugin.