# How to use XSLT 2.0 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, xslt

In the [Release Notes of WTP 3.1.0](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/sourceediting.php) they talk about WTP supporting XSLT 2.0.
I have Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with WTP installed, but

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />
```

still always returns `1.0`.

So how can I use XSLT 2.0 in Eclipse?
When I go to the preference, I have the Xalan 2.7.1 option selected.

Comment: Installed Saxon HE 9

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same issue myself and was only able to solve it - just as @ivoronline commented - by manually adding Saxon HE9 as the standard XSLT processor. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7737731/1955204

After you have downloaded SAXON you can set the Eclipse standard processor at:

1. Run
2. Runtime Configurations
3. Select your XSL Configuration on the left
4. Open the "Processor" tab
5. "Change Preferences"
6. "Add" new processor
7. Enter a name and select type as Saxon 2.0
8. Use "Add Workspace JARs" or "Add External JARs" and route
   to the downloaded jar file
9. Check the newly added, hit ok and run

Comment: The only problem one might get is, that it does not support debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Wikipedia in German:

"
Release 2.7.1 von Xalan unterstützt die W3C-Standards XSLT 1.0 und XPath 1.0. Deren Nachfolger XSLT 2.0 und XPath 2.0 werden von Xalan nicht unterstützt (Stand März 2011). "

Translated:

XALAN 2.7.1 does not support XSLT 2.0.